# why did i got IndexError: list index out of range message?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
import urllib # cmd- pip install requests
import bs4 # 실행전cmd- pip install BeautifulSoup4 설치
import matplotlib.pyplot  # 만들어진 데이터 포인트를 graph로 출력, 사용하기전 cmd-pip install matplotlib 실행
from datetime import datetime
company=input('찾으시고 싶은 회사명을 Ticker는 stock symbol로 적어주세요(ex)apple=appl) :' )

def get_company_data(company):
    findothercompany=company # https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/dividend-history 창에서 appl부분을 인풋값으로 변환
    data=[] # 공백 리스트 형식으로 append 함수를 이용해 추가할 예정
    dividendplot=[] # 공백 리스트에 데이터값을 받아와서 plot함수를 이용해 graph를 그린다.
    url='https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/'+findothercompany+'/dividend-history' # nasdaq사이트에서 dividend history를 찾는것 없을수도 있다.
    print('본 데이터는 NASDAQ의 '+url+'를 참고한 것입니다.')
    tables=bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(),features='lxml').find_all('table')# lxml은 코드들을 html 형식으로 가져오는것 (1조 발표  html형식)
    #print(len(tables))
    dividend_data=tables[2].find_all('tr')
    #print(dividend_data[0])
    #print(dividend_data[1])
    for tr in dividend_data[1:]:
        tds=tr.find_all('td')
        exdate=tds[0].text
        Type=tds[1].text
        CashAmount=tds[2].text
        Declarationdate=tds[3].text
        Recorddate=tds[4].text
        Paymentdate=tds[5].text
        data.append([exdate,Type,CashAmount,Declarationdate,Recorddate,Paymentdate])
        dividendplot.append([Paymentdate,float(CashAmount)])

    return data,dividendplot


dividenddata,dividendplot=get_company_data(company)
print(dividenddata)
```

then I got this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/월토커/Desktop/금융소프트웨어 project.py", line 32, in <module>
    dividenddata,dividendplot=get_company_data(company)
  File "C:/Users/월토커/Desktop/금융소프트웨어 project.py", line 22, in get_company_data
    Declarationdate=tds[3].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I think you should start debugging your code by printing the content of the `tds` array and see what's it like. Most probably it will have less than 3 elements....

Comment: Obviously there a `tr` that has 3 `tds`.

Comment: the problem is  when i type appl. but when i type dal it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is fine but `appl` has no data, check https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/appl/dividend-history try with another like `ppl`

check your `td` length if it length lower than 6 skip the loop

```
tds=tr.find_all('td')
if len(tds) < 6:
    continue # or break
```